# Find Maximum date SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using below query to find max date,getting output as "30-12-2017" , whereas the output should be "15-12-2018" .my sample data is attached, data type is nvarchar and SQL Server 2008.

```
select MAX(date1) from tblMonth
```

[image]

Comment: *data type is nvarchar* - WHY???

Comment: If it looks like a date, smells like a date, walks and talks like a date - it probably ***IS*** a date and should be stored as such (using `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` datatypes). Do ***NOT*** just squeeze everything into a string because it's "easier" to handle.... it's not - you run into issues like these - over and over again. Use the **most appropriate** datatype - ***always!***

Comment: Actually same is working in oracle, I need to get it work in SQL also

Answer (score 3):

Your datatype for Date1 seems to be `nvarchar`. The `MAX()` on `nvarchar`'s is a string compare. The string `30-12-2017` starts with `30`, which has the biggest ASCII code in your example. If you enter `31-11-2017`, this would be the result of `MAX(date1)`.

Use a date datatype (i.e. [`datetime2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/bb677335(v=sql.120).aspx) or [`date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql)) instead and it will work as you expect.